# what is the ionization rate?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I'm wondering about the term "ionization rate". Especially in respect to silicon/semi conductors and electrons & holes. I do not understand why there is a difference between electrons & holes. From my understanding, at each time an electron is generated a hole will be generated too. How is a difference possible?

For example: [Ionization rate si - electrons and holes](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.109.1537)

[Detailed description](http://www.iue.tuwien.ac.at/phd/triebl/node20.html)

Comment: It is in the context of avalanche, so I'm not sure why you think electrons and holes should be the same. In particular, the effective masses of the two are different.

Comment: Isn't it that when an electron is released an hole is generated too? That makes me thinking that the ration of electrons and holes should be always the same. Despite from the fact the recombinate differently - but in regards to "ionization rate" it shouldn't matter? In other words: Ionization rate means for me "generation rate". Is this maybe the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not understand why there is a difference between electrons &
>   holes. From my understanding, at each time an electron is generated a
>   hole will be generated too. How is a difference possible?

The difference between electrons and holes here is that they have different ability to ionize silicon atoms or produce new electron-hole pairs.

Each ionization event, whether it is caused by an electron or a hole, produces one electron and one hole, as you expected.

Comment: That means, once an electron-hole pair is produced the "ionization rate" of both - to ionize through their trajectory, is different? And this is meant by ionization rate? In other words: Once an electron-hole pair is produced, the electron will cause much more further electron-hole pairs than the origin hole?

Comment: @Ben Exactly. You got it.

Comment: @Ben Glad to help.